# How to get back my sent mails?

Tags: restore, email

After Sent mails using command-line mail utility:

```
mail -s subject someuser@example.com
...
```

If I have misspelled the recipient mail address, or I want to review my old mails which have already been sent, how to do?

Comment: "How to get back my sent emails" reminds me of http://www.27bslash6.com/overdue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mail` program may have the following option:

```
     record  If defined, gives the pathname of the file used to record all
             outgoing mail.  If not defined, outgoing mail is not saved.
             Default is norecord.
```

See `man mail` for more details on how to set the `record` option.

Answer (score 3):

You can't unless the content of the mail is logged elsewhere (say for example, your outgoing mail server is set to record all content of all outgoing mail) which is unlikely unless you yourself (or your program/script if you called `mail` from such) stored a copy.

The `mail` program does what it says on the tin and nothing else: it sends the mail and doesn't store it anywhere.

Comment: What he said...in other words: You're F'K'D!

Comment: ...unless you set the `record` option in your mail program (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unless your mail server is logging them, there isn't any way.